# MySQL Query - Records between Today and Last 30 Days

Tags: mysql, date, select

I want to return all records that were added to the database within the last 30 days.  I need to convert the date to mm/dd/yy because of display purposes.

```
create_date between DATE_FORMAT(curdate(),'%m/%d/%Y') AND (DATE_FORMAT(curdate() - interval 30 day,'%m/%d/%Y'))
```

My statement fails to limit the records to the last 30 days - it selects all the records.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  It feels like I am close.

Thanks and have a great week.

Answer (score 373, accepted):

You need to apply `DATE_FORMAT` in the `SELECT` clause, not the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM    mytable
WHERE   create_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Also note that `CURDATE()` returns only the `DATE` portion of the date, so if you store `create_date` as a `DATETIME` with the time portion filled, this query will not select the today's records.

In this case, you'll need to use `NOW` instead:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM    mytable
WHERE   create_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

Comment: The second part of this answer is very important! I may or may not have had that problem and I was scratching my head until I came back to this answer.

Comment: @Quassnoi I'm sorry. This seems to be WordPress \wpdb prepare problem only.
Sorry again.

Answer (score 72):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    < table_name >
WHERE
    < date_field > BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
AND NOW();
```

Comment: I prefer this method to BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30

Comment: @ErmSo can I know why?

Comment: I won't lie - that was 2 years ago and I can't remember! Sorry :P

Comment: No need to use `DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: @Dan I prefer to make it more readable by enclosing the previous date in parentheses:

`... WHERE create_date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()`

Answer (score 17):

You can also write this in mysql -

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM    mytable
WHERE   create_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH);
```

**FIXED**

Comment: Beware: despite the up-votes, this selects dates in the *next* 30 days/month, not the *last* 30 days!

Comment: Agreed, should be 

WHERE   create_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH);

Answer (score 14):

`DATE_FORMAT` returns a string, so you're using two strings in your `BETWEEN` clause, which isn't going to work as you expect.

Instead, convert the date to your format in the `SELECT` and do the `BETWEEN` for the actual dates. For example,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%m/%d/%y') as create_date_formatted
FROM table
WHERE create_date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 8):

For the current date activity and complete activity for previous 30 days use this, since the SYSDATE is variable in a day the previous 30th day will not have the whole data for that day.

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM mytable
WHERE create_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND SYSDATE()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a formulation not shown in the other answers, showing that the last 30 days worth of data can be returned without the "BETWEEN" operator and/or DATE_ADD()/DATE_SUB() functions:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%m/%d/%y') 
FROM table
WHERE create_date > (curdate() - interval 30 day);
```

Note if you are storing just the date, use curdate(), if you have a timestamp, use now().

See Quassnoi's answer for a description of why that is.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution without using `curdate()` function, this is a solution for those who use `TSQL` I guess

```
SELECT myDate
FROM myTable
WHERE myDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```