# Get from database but only last 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm using this php to fetch data from my mysql database:

```
$wpdb->get_var("select count(*) from " . $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter where status='C'"); ?>
```

You may notice i'm in wordpress so i'm using the $wpdb variable.

This returns all data from the table where `status='C'`. This is all working fine but I need to only get the data from the past 30 days. I'm not sure if mysql stores data about when this entry was stored but I do have another column called `created` in the same row as `status`. This stores the date in the following format:

`2011-10-14 15:33:58`

Is there any way to use that to update my code to only retreive the data from the past month?

Any advise here is greatly appreciated.

Thanks C

Comment: you could have searched first before asking. How about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041575/mysql-query-records-between-today-and-last-30-days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is adddate() function in MySQL wich you can use for this :)

```
$wpdb->get_var("select count(*) from " . $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter where status='C' and date_format(created,'%Y%m%d')>date_format(adddate(now(),interval -30 day),'%Y%m%d')");
```

This one is for 30 days back but you can replace the "interval -30 day" with "interval -1 month" or visit [dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) where you have all explained.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your query:

```
select count(*) from " . $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter where status='C' 
AND DATE(created)>=DATE_SUB(CUR_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $wpdb->get_var("select count(*) from " . $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter where status='C'
 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), created) <= 30"); ?>
```

Used:

> DATEDIFF() - returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from
>   one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time
>   expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the
>   calculation.

And:

> CURDATE() - Current date