# Getting mysql result from the last 30 days

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get from database but only last 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616869/get-from-database-but-only-last-30-days)

Hi I have some php code which I use to count the rows in a database from the last 30 days.  The problem is, that if I change the piece of code so that the number changes from `-30` to `-20`, the output number goes from `272` to `360` instead of going down.

Here is the code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM all_count WHERE DATEDIFF(date,NOW()) = -30 and member ='000002'");
$num_rows60 = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Same question in full description http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912035/display-record-older-than-3-months-in-sql/13912197#13912197

Comment: You are selecting records that are *exactly* 30 or 20 days old.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from `table` where `yourfield` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

For days, year see below for example.

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) /*For getting record specific days*/

DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) /*for getting records specific years*/
```

---

For Anand, query

```
BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 6 MONTH ) AND DATE_SUB( CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 3 MONTH ) 
/* For Getting records between last 6 month to last 3 month
```

Comment: Wow very nice this Fully Explained

Comment: Thanks, your explanation really helped me understand the difference and how it should be done. Perfect thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's better to compare

```
`date`< DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

rather than

```
 DATEDIFF(date,NOW()) = -30
```

In the first case, the date calculation is done only once, at the beginning of the query, and the database can use any indexes on the date column.

The second query must calculate the `DATEDIFF` on every row, and the database can't use any indexes.  The second query forces a full table scan.

Also, I strongly suggest that you not call your column `date`.  Yes, I know you can quote the name with backticks, but that's just messy and when you forget then your syntax errors will be hard to forget.  Come up with a more descriptive name for the column.  What kind of date is it?  What does the date represent?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this instead:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM all_count WHERE `date`< DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) and     member ='000002'");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), the `DATEDIFF` function in MySQL tells you the difference in days of the first date to the second.

Your query only selects all rows where the difference is exactly 30 days and not those that are up to 30 days ago. So it's completely possible, that the number of rows for the date 20 days ago is higher than 30 days ago. What you most likely wanted was:

```
SELECT * FROM all_count WHERE DATEDIFF(date,NOW()) >= -30 and member ='000002'
```