# upper limit for active records in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have this function in my model the purpose of it is to get the stats of the past  30 days starting from the actual day, it was working fine before i reach 30th day then I found out it is counting from the oldest date, so I flipped the order_by from "ase" to "desc" but it seems still going back and counting before the oldest day and not giving me that data I want, so I'm wondering if there any way using codeigniter and give a starting point for the "limit" which should be the actual date.

```
function graph_data($id_person)
{
    $this->db->limit(30);   // get data for the last 30 days including the curent day

    $this->db->where('personid',$id_person);
    $this->db->order_by('date', 'ase');
    $query = $this->db->get('stats');   

    foreach($query-> result_array() as $row)
    {
     $data[] = $row;
    }    
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Did you mean to use `ASC`? It's not `ase`... What data type is `date`?

Comment: No I mean ase, and the type of the date is just DATE in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution by giving a range or days, 29 days before the actual day without using BETWEEN and that works fine

```
<?php
function graph_data($id_person)
{   
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$lastdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-29 days', strtotime($today)));// 30 days ago

$this->db->where('personid',$id_person);
$this->db->where("date <= '$today'");
$this->db->where("date >= '$lastdate'");
$this->db->order_by('date', 'ase');

$query = $this->db->get('stats');   

$data = array();

foreach($query-> result_array() as $row)
{
 $data[] = $row;
}    

return $data;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

limit returns in your case the last 30 rows.  It has nothing to do with dates, unless you only add a row each day.

try using mysql [Between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM    mytable
WHERE   create_date BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND SYSDATE()
ORDER BY create_date ASC
```

Source -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2041619/337055

Comment: is it necessary to put DATE_FORMAT?