# MySQL Query - SELECT all records where current date is in between a date_to and last 30 day of that date_to

Tags: mysql

Hello everyone I hope you can help me on this

I have a table `m_membership_list` and there are fields `date_from` and `date_to` and I need to count the number of the records where current date is between `date_to` and the last_30 days of the the `date_to`.

I searched about this but I did not find the exact example but I think the logic is like in
[MySQL Query - Records between Today and Last 30 Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041575/mysql-query-records-between-today-and-last-30-days)

But still I can't get it.

Here is my SQL.

`SELECT * FROM m_membership_list WHERE NOW() IN DATE_SUB(date_to, INTERVAL 30 DAY)`

I think the logic is almost like this but i dont know why it is not working.

`SELECT * FROM m_membership_list WHERE NOW() BETWEEN date_to AND (DATE_SUB(date_to,INTERVAL 30 DAY))`Improv

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [`expr BETWEEN min AND max`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

> If ***`expr`*** is greater than or equal to ***`min`*** and ***`expr`*** is less than or equal to ***`max`***, [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) returns `1`, otherwise it returns `0`.

Since `NOW()` cannot simultaneously be greater than or equal to `date_to` **and** less than or equal to `DATE_SUB(date_to,INTERVAL 30 DAY)`, your clause is necessarily always false.  Reverse the operands:

```
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN DATE_SUB(date_to,INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND date_to
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but i encountered this to xammp  Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC), (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE), (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'between'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM m_membership_list
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 30 DAY AND date_to;
```

Comment: This will fetch ALL records from the table.

Comment: Hello i already try that but the problem is it still selecting all the data before the 1month before the date_to

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM m_membership_list 
WHERE TO_DAYS( NOW( ) ) - TO_DAYS( date_to) <=30
```