# How to get the last month of data in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need the last month of recorded data, not the data from current date -1 month.

Here my wrong query:D

```
SELECT  MIN(date(Timestamp)) as fDate , MAX(date(Timestamp)) as tDate  FROM data WHERE boxid=45 AND
 YEAR(Timestamp) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(Timestamp) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

EDIT:  i have much data in my table, i just want to see where the last recoded data starts and where it ends, but i want the last month.

example , table has recoded till january 17th. 
i want now 2 dates:  January 1st and 17th

I tried this

```
SELECT max(date(Timestamp)) as toDate, min(date(timestamp)) as fromDate FROM data WHERE timestamp<=(SELECT MAX(date(Timestamp)) FROM data )
AND timestamp>=(SELECT (MAX(date(Timestamp))- INTERVAL 1 MONTH) FROM data ) AND ID=10
```

it has a strange behavior , its giving me not 30 days...

Comment: Tried a query selecting the last 30 days?

Comment: yes i need the last month, actually only the 2 dates, where the last months data start and where it ends, thats why i used max() and min()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041575/mysql-query-records-between-today-and-last-30-days ?

Comment: no , because its from current day, till last 30 days. I need only last 30 days that can be 1899 january1st- 1899 january 31th

Comment: @Khan, If i am not wrong, you have the data with dates like  "2016-08-01", "2016-08-13","2016-08-17",  "2016-09-01", "2016-09-02","2016-09-03". Now you want to select the records where date is matching with "2016-08-01", "2016-08-13","2016-08-17".  Is it correct?

Comment: Then you need to do a first select to get the last timestamp and use this instead of CURRENT_DATE

Comment: yes that sounds right  how can i use this instead of CURRENT_DATE

Comment: Guys u have understood my question :D now help

Answer (score 1):

Alright so to try this I created a table called 'recordings' which only contains `id` (int) and `timestamp` (timestamp).

Here's the content of the table:

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM `recordings` WHERE `timestamp` <= ( SELECT `timestamp` FROM `recordings` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1 ) AND `timestamp` >= (( SELECT `timestamp` FROM `recordings` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1 ) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

And I got this:
[image]
Which is exactly the recordings from 1 month before the last one

Comment: thats what i need but its giving me a syntax error :( #1064

Comment: Can you copy and paste your exact query please?

Comment: i copied your query and replaced recordings with data

Comment: What about timestamp? Have you changed the case? Also I forgot ticks (`) in my answer, that may cause errors depending on your version of MySQL - I have corrected it since

Answer (score 0):

The first day of the last available month of data is given by:

```
MAX(DATE(`Timestamp`)) - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(`Timestamp`) - 1 ) DAY
-- e.g., 2016-09-16 - INTERVAL (16 - 1) DAY => 2016-09-01
```

and the latest available day is simply

```
MAX(DATE(`Timestamp`))
```

So you can

```
SELECT last_day - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(last_day) - 1) DAY AS first_day,
       last_day
  FROM (SELECT MAX(DATE(`Timestamp`)) AS last_day FROM data) derived;
```

(You don't need that derived table, of course, but I find that more readable than repeating *max(date(`blah`))* over and over.)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Member
WHERE DATEPART(m, date_created) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, date_created) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

Comment: Some explanation would be great.

Comment: I didn't downtick you but I think it is because this doesn't allow you to fetch any month, only last month.  I personally would use your answer.  It's the simplest.  I'll uptick you :)