# SQL: Delete fields value after an amount of time

Tags: mysql, sql

Im new at SQL and Im currently using it for one of my projects.

I want to delete the data in a **field** eg. if it was not changed for 30 days.

I thought of something like this - `DELETE eventLog WHERE date < (lastChange - INTERVAL 30 DAY);`

1. eventLog is a varchar
2. lastChange is a DATE

I tried it but I think it does not really worked.

Does somone has a better way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELETE` does not remove values from a field. For `varchar` you want something like:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET eventLog = ''
WHERE ...
```

OR

```
UPDATE tableName
SET eventLog = NULL
WHERE ...
```

`DELETE` is used to remove entire rows from a table.

Also as for the last 30 days part see this:

[MySQL Query - Records between Today and Last 30 Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041575/mysql-query-records-between-today-and-last-30-days)

Comment: Thanks. Can I use this in the  same script, in which my tabel is created, because it should update the tabel, everytime the eventLog was not changed for 30 Days?

Comment: @jokey I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: So just put it in a script that runs twice a day... sorry still not sure what isn't clear. Maybe some more details on how you are running it would help.