# How to get list of customers that haven't order in last 30 Days in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table

1. `laces_users_profile`
2. `laces_order`

`laces_order` have order list of all user.
`laces_users_profile` have all customer data.

`laces_users_profile` have unique key `laces_user_id` that is foreign key in `laces_order`.

My Tables look like this

**laces_orders**

[image]

**laces_users_profile**

[image]

**I want to retrieve all customers, Who have not order from last 30 Days.**

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041575/mysql-query-records-between-today-and-last-30-days, you need not between

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: You should consider using a more consistent naming convention across your database. For example, if the table is called `laces_users_profile`, the order should have a `laces_user_profile_id` or something rather than `customer_id`. Or you should call the `laces_users_profile` table `customers`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Query - Records between Today and Last 30 Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041575/mysql-query-records-between-today-and-last-30-days)

Comment: What if I add customer today? I will also considered as customer not given order in last 30 day. It should not happen. Recently added customer should not come in list of those customer who did not given order since last 30 days. how achieve that condition. @BadHorsie

Comment: What if I add customer today? I will also considered as customer not given order in last 30 day. It should not happen. Recently added customer should not come in list of those customer who did not given order since last 30 days. how achieve that condition. @LarryTang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `left join` antipattern:

```
select u.*
from laces_users_profiles u
left join laces_order o
    on o.customer_id = u.laces_user_id 
    and o.create_date > now() - interval 30 day
where o.customer_id is null
```

The same result can be achieved with a `not exists` condition and a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*
from laces_users_profiles u
where not exists (
    select 1
    from join laces_order o
    where 
        o.customer_id = u.laces_user_id 
        and o.create_date > now() - interval 30 day

)
```

Comment: Thanks !! @GMB Its Working !!

Comment: What if I add customer today? I will also considered as customer not given order in last 30 day. It should not happen. Recently added customer should not come in list of those customer who did not given order since last 30 days. how achieve that condition.  @GMB